# Using ssh reverse tunnel as gateway to reach machine under NAT

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling, port-forwarding, nat, gateway

I'd like to reach a machine under a network with NAT and without port forwarding.

The machine "closed" behind the no-port-forwarding NAT is called RaspberryB.
This machine create a reverse tunnel with a machine (RaspberryA) that is reachable thanks to a port-forwarding on port 22 and has local IP 192.168.1.34.

So on RaspberryB i launched the command
 `ssh -R 43022:localhost:22 userA@addressRaspA`

On RaspberryA I can connect back through the reverse tunnel:

`ssh userB@localhost -p 43022`

and it works.

From a PC in the same network I can connect to RaspberryA and then to RaspberryB (I'm using putty under windows, but I think is irrelevant)

`ssh userA@192.168.1.34       <<-- after this i'm inside RaspberryA`

`ssh userB@localhost -p 43022 <<-- after this i'm inside RaspberryB`

So now I've achieved what I need, access raspberryB from the PC in another network.

**But**, i'd like to do this in one passage only... I thought that, if from the PC I issue the command:

`ssh userB@192.168.1.34 -p 43022`

thgen my PC should connect to the 43022 port of RaspberryA, being redirect to port 22 of RaspberryB and so I should be able to connect to rapsberryB with a single command.

But i get "**Network Error: Connection Refused**"

I don't think it's a firewall issue, since if (on RaspA) I temconfigure ssh to listen to 43022 port the PC can connect, but just in case this is my **iptables -S** output

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
f2b-sshd   tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             multiport dports ssh

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain f2b-sshd (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

So, where I am doing wrong?
why the PC in the same network of RaspberryA cannot reach raspberryB with the last single command?

edit: forgot to mention, I also tried open the ssh with
`ssh -R 1.1.1.1:43023:localhost:22 pi@addressRaspA`
I don't really understant deeply if the 1.1.1.1 is correct for making a gateway or if the remote host is tring to connect to all PC in the network.. nonetheless, still "Connection Refused" message

edit 2: I'd like to be able to access to raspberryB from any PC on the network, so creating a remote tunnel to a specific ip is not an option. Best if ita can work also from outside the network, it's possible to openening port forwading on the router of the raspberryA network

[image: network diagram]

Answer (score 1):

Resolved:
Errors in what i've done:

first of all, 1.1.1.1 is not "all ips".
0.0.0.0 is.

second, I need to activate "GatewayPorts in ssh configuration

So:

1. Edit /etc/ssh/sshd_config , setting `GatewayPorts clientspecified`
2. start reverse tunne with the command
   `ssh -fN -R 0.0.0.0:43022:localhost:22 rasbberryA@addressRaspA`